# How to remove the x-axis showing up for the bottom?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to figure out how I can remove that line as seen in the picture with ChartJS. I can't seem to find anything about it in the documentation either, everything is so vague.

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="chartContainer">
    <canvas class="overviewChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var ctx = document.getElementsByClassName("overviewChart")[0].getContext('2d');
        var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 400);
        gradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(0,169,255,0.2)');
        gradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(0,169,255,0)');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
                datasets: [{
                    data: [10, 15, 18, 20, 32, 30, 29, 25, 13, 17, 16, 24],
                    backgroundColor: gradient,
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgb(0,169,255)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 4
                }]
            },
            options: {
                legend: {
                    display: false
                },
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        gridLines: {
                            color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero:true,
                            fontColor: 'white'
                        }
                    }],

                    xAxes: [{
                        gridLines: {
                            color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            fontColor: 'white',
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
        myChart.canvas.parentNode.style.height = '400px';
```

I have tried everything from

```
gridLines: {
  drawBorder: false,
  color: 'transparent'
}
```

to

```
scaleLineColor: 'transparent'
```

..but nothing works. Any idea on how I can solve this problem?

Comment: What is ctx? If you would post a runnable example it would take ten seconds to get an answer

Comment: My mistake. Updated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm personally of the opinion charts should start at 0 wherever possible, so setting `beginAtZero: false` isn't a viable solution. I simply set the axis option `zeroLineColor` to transparent:

```
options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
                zeroLineColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! For anyone who has the same issue, this is caused by `beginAtZero:true`. Simply change it to `false` and it will disappear.